# Simple Unix way of looping through space-delimited strings?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have a file, called `file_list`, containing space-delimited strings, each of which is a file name of a file to be processed. I now wish to loop through all the file names and process them one by one. Pseudocode is

```
for every filename in file_list
    process(filename);
end
```

I have come up with a rather clumsy solution, which is

1. load the file into a variable by `filenames='cat file_list'`
2. count the number of spaces, `N`, by `tr -cd ' ' <temp_list | wc -c`
3. loop from 1 to `N` and parse by space each file name out with `cut`

Is there an easier/more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try `for fname in $file_list`? What shell are you using?

Comment: @DaveNewton No, I haven't. Will that work? (a little bit surprised it is so simple) I am using bash.

Comment: @DaveNewton It actually works! Thanks a lot! Shocked by my stupidness.. LOL

Comment: `for fname in $file_list` should _not_ work: that loops over the names inside the _variable_ `$file_name`.  But in your question you said it was not a variable, but the name of a file.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is a classic trick that's been in the bourne shell for a while.

```
for filename in `cat file_list`; do
  # Do stuff here
done
```

Comment: Does not work if any of the filenames can contain spaces or other shell globbing characters. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor . Though given the OP that might not be possible here.

Comment: @EtanReisner None of the file names are even able to contain spaces because they're *delimited* by spaces.  Also, I doubt that you have a file named *.

Comment: Doubt is not a proper substitute for safety. A file with `[1]` in the name can also cause problems, for example. And yes, as I edited my comment to say in this case that solution is safer than in others because the main problem is actually the intended behaviour but the rest are still possible.

Comment: @EtanReisner True, so this is definitely not a program that should be run with root privileges or over a network.  Although it does give shell globing as a feature.

Comment: If bash, use the builtin `for filename in $(< file_list)`

Answer (score 34):

Here is another approach which works in bash that no one has posted:

```
str="a b c d"

for token in ${str}; do
    echo "$token"
done
```

You mileage may vary running this in other shells.

Comment: doesn't work for me. echos "a b c d", not "a" "b" "c" "d". Using bash

Comment: @chaylan did you quote ${str}?  This will only split if ${str} is unquoted.

Comment: I took this approach but had to throw in echo, like `for token in $(echo ${str}); do`

Comment: This works in `bash` but not in `zsh` which might explain why some people find it works and others don't.

Answer (score 15):

You can change the file to have words be line separated instead of space separated. This way, you can use the typical syntax:

```
while read line
do
   do things with $line
done < file
```

With `tr ' ' '\n' < file` you replace spaces with new lines, so that this should make:

```
while read line
do
   do things with $line
done < <(tr ' ' '\n' < file)
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello this is a set of strings
$ while read line; do echo "line --> $line"; done < <(tr ' ' '\n' < a)
line --> hello
line --> this
line --> is
line --> a
line --> set
line --> of
line --> strings
```

Comment: No need for `tr`. Use arrays instead. Since you are using process substitution it is safe to assume that shell is bash. `while IFS= read -ra filename; do printf "file -- %s\n" ${filename[@]}; done < a`

Answer (score 3):

`xargs` would also work here for a nice 1-liner. it splits by any whitespace by default.

```sh
xargs -n 1 process <file_list
```

or to place the filename within the command:

```sh
# mac
xargs -n 1 -J % process(%) <file_list
# unix
xargs -n 1 -d " " -i process({}) <file_list
```